# Is there any opportunities to override SQLite Connection Open method in C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite, autofac

I need to execute a SQliteCommand every time when Connection opened. And I'm going to to inherit SQliteConnection class and register custom class using Autofac, but this way doesn't work work for me.

Comment: Why not have your own connect method that connects and does this special thing, then just call that.

Comment: Would it be an option to write an [Extensionmenthod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) "SpecialOpen" ?

Comment: Look at the `StateChange` event.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an `is a` relationship use an `has a` relationship - Don't inherit `SQliteConnection`, instead, encapsulate it inside your class.

Something like this should get you started:

```
public class DBHelper
{
    private readonly string _connectionString,
                            _sqlToExecuteOnConnectionOpen;

    public DBHelper(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
        _sqlToExecuteOnConnectionOpen = "Your sql goes here";
    }

    public void ExecuteSql(Action<SQliteConnection> action)
    {
        using(var con = new SQliteConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            using(var cmd = new SQliteCommand(_sqlToExecuteOnConnectionOpen, con)
            {
                con.Open();
                // of course, any parameters goes here...
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            }
            action(con);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you have a method that opens and disposes an instance of `SqliteConnection`, execute your pre-detenrmined sql, and whatever other action you want to execute with that connection.

You can even take it one step further and have this method private, but expose public methods for ExecuteNonQuery, ExecuteScalar, ExecuteReader and even filling a dataset or data table - and have them all execute this method. 
This can save you a lot of the repetitive plumbing code usually written when using ADO.Net.

In fact, I've published a [project on GitHub](https://github.com/Peled-Zohar/ADONETHelper) that does exactly that (except your constant sql statement, of course) - You can clone it, view it's code, and just generally take ideas from it and implement them in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) principle to intercept the `Open` method.

Let's start by implementing your custom interceptor.

```
public class PrepareConnectionInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        if (!(invocation.InvocationTarget is IDbConnection 
              && invocation.Method.Name == nameof(IDbConnection.Open)))
        {
            invocation.Proceed();
            return; 
        }

        invocation.Proceed();
        IDbConnection connection = (IDbConnection)invocation.InvocationTarget;
        using(IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SQL statement";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Then register your connection and interceptor using *autofac*

```
builder.RegisterType<PrepareConnectionInterceptor>()
       .AsSelf();
builder.RegisterType<SQLiteConnection>()
        .As<IDbConnection>()
        .EnableInterfaceInterceptors()
        .InterceptedBy(typeof(PrepareConnectionInterceptor));
```

Now each time you call the `Open` method on a resolved `IDbConnection` the interceptor will be triggered and custom SQL will be executed.

You can find more information on the [Autofac Interceptor documentation](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html)